What is the safe way to conditional wrap input with state
Previously, I check if error exist and wrap the input and error message in div conditionally. This incur a problem that the input lose focus when re-render. Is there any way to wrap the input conditionally, I don't want input to be wrap by div when error is not exist.
Below is my code without conditional wrapping:
import * as React from "react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { FieldError } from "react-hook-form";
import ErrorText from "../shared/ErrorText";

export interface InputProps
  extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  error?: FieldError | undefined;
  errorClassName?: string;
}

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  ({ className, type, error, errorClassName, ...props }, ref) => {
    return <div className="flex flex-col">
      <input
        type={type}
        className={cn(
          "flex h-12 w-full rounded-xl border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-md file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50",
          className
        )}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
      {error && <ErrorText className={errorClassName}>{error.message}</ErrorText>}
    </div>
  }
)
Input.displayName = "Input"

export { Input }

Below is my code with conditional wrapping. This lose focus when re-render (error message change):
export interface InputProps
  extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  error?: FieldError | undefined;
  errorClassName?: string;
}

const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  ({ className, type, error, errorClassName, ...props }, ref) => {
    const child = (
      <>
        <input
          type={type}
          className={cn(
            "flex h-12 w-full rounded-xl border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-md file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50",
            className
          )}
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
        />
      </>
    )

    if (error) {
      return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
          {child}
          {<ErrorText className={errorClassName}>{error.message}</ErrorText>}
        </div>
      )
    }
    return child;
  }
)
Input.displayName = "Input"

export { Input }


It is not possible in React to conditionally change the element hierarchy (i.e. the JSX nesting, i.e. wrapping a JSX element inside another JSX element conditionally).
React renders the input element in these two cases as different elements, i.e. not as the same element at a different position. The elements identity depends on it's position, not (only) on the JSX code (See also the "Pitfall" section under Same component at the same position preserves state).
This is one of the assumptions React makes to be able to optimize the rendering process:

Two elements of different types will produce different trees.

